# How to get html output from javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript from textarea:

```
<textarea id="result">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.php"></script>
</textarea>
```

I want to get html from this javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".submit").click(function(){
        var html = $('#result').val();
        $('#content').html(html);
    });
});
</script>
<input type="button" class="submit" value="Ok" />
<div id="content"></div>
```

Result output is an error. How do I do this?

Comment: error is: load page, i want it no load page

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gFZ73/

Comment: Script elements inside of a textarea element? That's new to me. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @HaiTruong - See the console output here for why it may not be working the way you expect: http://jsfiddle.net/gFZ73/1/

Comment: @Jared Farrish: I think error from <script type="text/javascript" src="test.php"></script>

Comment: @HaiTruong - Since none of us have any idea what this file contains, etc., it will be difficult to help.

Answer (score 1):

use `var html = $('#result').html();`

demo http://jsfiddle.net/gFZ73/2/

Comment: You sure that will *fix* it? http://jsfiddle.net/gFZ73/3/ (My actual thought is the OP is looking for the script tag content, but you could be right.)

Comment: Hai Truong, are you looking for the content of the src files? or the textarea content?

Comment: If you want @HaiTruong to see the comment, add an `@` before the username. `:)`